# Emptying a directory with Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am looking for a way to empty a directory in Express.

Basically, I have a `tmp` directory where I am storing temporary files and every so often I just want to empty the folder of all files, but **not** delete the folder itself.

What is the best way to do this? I am currently using `Node v0.8.9` and `Express v.3.0.0rc4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either check this little but sweet module.

https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf

Or check the official docs and examples.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/fs.html#file_System

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function called remove folder.  It will recursively remove all the files and folders in a location.  The only package it requires is async.
    var async = require('async');

```
function removeFolder(location, removeFolder, next) {
    fs.readdir(location, function (err, files) {
        async.each(files, function (file, cb) {
            file = location + '/' + file
            fs.stat(file, function (err, stat) {
                if (err) {
                    return cb(err);
                }
                if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                    removeFolder(file, true, cb);
                } else {
                    fs.unlink(file, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            return cb(err);
                        }
                        return cb();
                    })
                }
            })
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err)
            fs.rmdir(location, function (err) {
                return next(err)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

I changed it a little to not remove the original folder call it using:

```
removeFolder('/tmp', false, function(err){
    //callback
})
```